# In case of an exception in webservice is the control returned to to UI with error?

Tags: java, angular, rest, web-services

I have a UI page developed using angular js and make a rest webservice call. If an exception is thrown by webservice will the control be returned to the UI with the error?

Comment: If it's not caught you'll get a HTTP 500 status.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it will be returned to the client. This is true even if the server timesouts.

But it might not be in a format as you expected. For example, you might have sent a json request and expecting a json response. But you might get an html response if the server has setup a simple html handler for error code. In this case your response parsing will fail. One common example is the authentication failure, which simply redirects you to html login page in many services.

So before parsing the result, check the status code. Check the service rest api docs and study the error handling semantics. Then parse the error accordingly.